# Identify a game involving placing cardboard food into a mouth using forks

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to remember what game was just a heads and neck made of cardboard. It came with forks and cardboard junk food. You had to put the food in the mouth one at a time then it would tip and dump it out

Comment: Sounds like the opposite of Operation.

Comment: When were you a child? What country did you live in as a child? What language were the game's instructions in?

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly *[Big Mouth](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21461/big-mouth)*, published by Schaper in 1968 (BoardGameGeek also lists Hasbro as a publisher, but doesn't list a specific version that they published).

[image: Big Mouth game]

This seems to match most of your description. From the website:

> Each player is given a large 14" red plastic fork and a paper plate on which there are 6 different plastic food items and a green bug. A thin piece of cardboard is placed over a plastic bowl. The cardboard is designed in the shape of a cute clown with a hole forming the entrance to his oral cavity, which is formed by the bowl.

The biggest difference between your description and this one is that the food is plastic, not cardboard. It also doesn't look like there is a dumping mechanism, but everything else seems to fit.

<sub>If this doesn't quite fit your game, please let us know why and perhaps edit your question with more details</sub>